# How to keep the radio button enabled by default using Android XML

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

```
      <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />
```

I've used this code but not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you misunderstand the meaning of enabled, that happens often by beginners. 
`android:enabled="true"` just means that the `RadioButton` is usable. For example, a not enabled `RadioButton` doesn´t react to user clicks. What you need is `checked`:

```
android:checked="true"
```

check out the Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html

Answer (score 0):

try it's!

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="RadioButton" />
```

Change:

```
android:enabled="true"
```

for:

```
android:checked="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

programmatically, you can use the setChecked method defined in the checkable interface:

```
RadioButton b = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option1);
b.setChecked(true);
```

I hope this will help you,All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
android:enabled="true"
```

Use this

```
android:checked="true"
```